# PowerShell crashes on `if ( $? = $false )`

Tags: powershell

I'm playing with PowerShell and I've encountered a crash that I can easily reproduce on my computer.

I'm not sure if the code is correct. However, running the following piece makes `powershell.exe` and `powershell_ise.exe` crash. I guess that my use of `if ( $? = $false )` is wrong, but crash should not happen in such case. Removing `If` statement helps to avoid the crash.

Is there anything I'm missing?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro and PowerShell 5.1.14393.206.

**Update 1**

OK, thanks to @Martin I know that I mistakenly used `=` instead of `-eq`. But why this crash happens?

**Update 2**

Filed a bug report to PowerShell UserVoice: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/16977433-assigning-a-value-to-false-crashes

**Update 3**

It seems to be a known bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2243 that should be fixed soon https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/2320

```powershell
Test-Path "C:\test"
if ( $? = $false ) {
    Out-Host "Hello World"
}
```

```powershell
Fault bucket 127386360339, type 5
Event Name: PowerShell
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: powershell.exe
P2: 10.0.14393.206
P3: stem.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCast
P4: stem.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCast
P5: ation.LanguagePrimitives.ThrowInvalidCastException
P6: ation.LanguagePrimitives.ThrowInvalidCastException
P7: Pipeli..ution Thread
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

Comment: Can confirm. PS console crashes when assigning any value to `$?` (version 5.1.14393.206)

Comment: And it seems not to happen with v5.0 (at least v5.0.10586.122). A proper error message about assigning a value to a read-only variable is displayed.

Comment: @Swonkie Please, click Vote Up at https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/16977433-assigning-a-value-to-false-crashes I've filed a bug report and your vote up could help. :)

Comment: I got the error by just typing $? = $false.  Powershell version  5.1.41393.206

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You are [**assigning**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847875.aspx) `$false` to the [question mark variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) which is a *read-only* variable. You probably want to replace the `=` with [`-eq`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx):

```
Test-Path "C:\test"
if ( $? -eq $false ) {
    Out-Host "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: Oops. Yep, I should've used `-eq` instead of trying to assign a new value. But PowerShell should not crash, and must tell me that I'm trying to run an invalid action.